# React ERROR AL RENDERIZAR

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";

import Square from "./Square";

export default class Count extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      moment: moment(),
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Square time={this.state.moment.hour()} />:
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

La pregunta es, por qué me dice que .hour() no es una función?, esa función existe en moment js, pierde el alcance?, realmente no sé que es lo que sucede, si pongo this.state.moment.hour() en un console.log si me da un resultado pero si lo intento renderizar en Square no puedo.

Comment: La funciona `hour()` funciona. Sin embargo, no sabemos qué es el componente `Square`. Probaste mostrar el resultado escribiendo simplemente `<div>{this.state.moment.hour()}</div>` ?

Comment: Sii, en un div sucede lo mismo :( el componente Square solo lo muestra en pantalla

Comment: que raro, aplique tu codigo en un codesandbox y me funciono bien, pero no logro entender por que a ti no te funciona, pero es necesario tener momento en el state, no veo algun beneficio en tenerlo en el state.